# works in chrome but not firefox - jquery

Tags: jquery, firefox, google-chrome, cross-browser

```
 $('#carat_weight_right li').css('left', function(index, value) {
   if (value === '100%') {

        $(this).children('span').css({'margin-left': '-58px', 'text-align': 'right'});
        alert('hello');

    }
 });
```

seems to work in chrome but not firefox any one have a clue ????

thanks

Comment: Has [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) been able to tell you anything?

Comment: Have a demo page we can look at? This isn't enough to go on.

Comment: what actually happens?  Does it blow up entirely and you never get the alert?  Do you get the alert but nothing happens?  Do you get the alert and bad things happen?  etc.

Comment: What doesn't work?  Does the alert even come up?

Comment: no alert nothing. ...a demo page is on http://www.arc-max.com/menuinsert/diamondsearch/diamond.php

Comment: I see alerts just fine on that page in Firefox 4....

Comment: I think this issue is related to this bug report: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11110

Answer (score 4):

This is a fun case of a cross-browser implementation difference.

Firefox is returning the `used value` for the element's `computed style`. This winds up being the actual value in pixels used to render the element in the browser: Firefox sees that 100%, decides in your layout that really equates to something like 326 pixels, and returns 326 pixels. [Mozilla talks about their implementation here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/used_value)

Chrome, on the other hand, returns the `specified value` ("100%") for the `computed style`.

The W3C kind of says both are valid: [returning the specified value is fine](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/changes.html#q36) if it can be done without the need for laying out the document; [returning the used value is OK](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#used-value) if that value can only be determined after layout is complete.

So what are you to do? Find a different way of making that cacluation. :-) Maybe check to see if your element's `position().left` is greater than or equal to its offset parent's `width()`?